# cURL (CLI): problems with textarea form and submit button

Tags: html, curl

First of all, sorry for my bad English. I am trying to send POST to the Filesonic Link Checker textarea.

This is the HTML source:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" id="redirect" />
<div class="field tTextarea" id="form_links_container"><label for="links" class="optional">Insert your links</label>
<div class="elements">
<textarea name="links" id="links" rows="24" cols="80">http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656894/file.part01.rar http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656884/file.part02.rar</textarea>
<div class="action">

<button name="controls[submit]" id="controls-submit" type="submit">Check</button></div></form>        </div>
```

I send the command in this way:

```
curl -d "links=blablabla%20blablabla" www.filesonic.it/link-checker
```

I've put %20 because is URL is encoded, and when I try to perform the POST operation with FireBug these are the variables sent:

```
controls[submit]:
links:http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656894/file.part01.rar http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656884/file.part02.rar
redirect:
```

So, where's the problem? Simple: when I try with curl, the HTML response is referred to only one link and it doesn't take the second one. I'll write how the response should be and what cURL gives to me.

Firefox:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="source"><span>http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656894/file.part01.rar</span></td>
<td class="fileName"><span>file.part01.rar</span></td>
<td class="fileSize"><span>953.67 MB</span></td>
<td class="availability"><span>
<strong style="font-weight: strong; color: green;">Available</strong><br />
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="source"><span>http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656884/file.part02.rar</span>    <td class="fileName"><span>-</span></td>
<td class="fileSize"><span>-</span></td>
<td class="availability"><span>
<strong style="font-weight: strong; color: red;">Not Available</strong><br />
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

cURL:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="source"><span>http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656894/file.part01.rar http://www.filesonic.it/file/3861656884/file.part02.rar</span></td>
<td class="fileName"><span>file.part01.rar</span></td>
<td class="fileSize"><span>953.67 MB</span></td>
<td class="availability"><span>
<strong style="font-weight: strong; color: green;">Available</strong><br />
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What's wrong with my POST? How should it be? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself. The problem is `%20`. ASCII `%20` is space, but in the text area the link have to stay one per line, so i've got to put NEWLINE ASCII HEX that is `0A`. So, the correct sintax for curl is:

```
curl -d "links=LINK1%0ALINK2%0ALINK3" www.filesonic.com/link-checker
```